# qglColor проблема при сборке проекта

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

Файл glscene.h:

```
#ifndef GLSCENE_H
#define GLSCENE_H
#include <QOpenGLWidget>    
class GLScene : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    GLScene(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLScene();

    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
};
#endif // GLSCENE_H
```

Файл glscene.cpp:

```
#include "glscene.h"
GLScene::GLScene(QWidget *parent):
    QOpenGLWidget(parent){}
GLScene::~GLScene(){}

void GLScene::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // заполняем экран белым цветом
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // задаем глубину проверки пикселей
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT); // убираем режим сглаживания цветов
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // говорим, что будем строить только внешние поверхности
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL); // фигуры будут закрашены с обеих сторон
}

void GLScene::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h); // установка точки обзора
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // установка режима матрицы
    glLoadIdentity(); // загрузка матрицы

}

void GLScene::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // очистка экрана
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // задаем модельно-видовую матрицу
    glLoadIdentity();           // загрузка единичную матрицу

    QColor halfGreen(0, 128, 0, 255); // устанавливаем цвет квадрата
    qglColor(halfGreen); // задаем цвет
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); // говорим, что рисовать будем прямоугольник
    // задаем вершины многоугольника
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();
}
```

Ошибка при сборке:

```
%path%\glscene.cpp:40: ошибка: 'qglColor' was not declared in this scope
     qglColor(halfGreen); // задаем цвет
                       ^
```

В pro-файле добавлен `QT += opengl`. Подключал `#include <QGLWidget>`, т.к. [документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QGLWidget.html) - не помогло.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что я наследую класс от `QOpenGLWidget`?

Comment: Действительно в этом была проблема. Но как тогда быть, если иcпользовать `QOpenGLWidget`?